# Access the entire URL path in RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Currently, my `RewriteRule` only works when I use the current path, for example loading the URL

```
http://localhost/rest/v1/test
```

Redirects to the URL:

```
http://localhost/rest/v1/index.php?url=test
```

Great. However, I want to be a bit cleverer about this and redirect to the correct version of the API so I don’t have these hard coded values. However my `RewriteRule` only works when I include the current path component. Here is my rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(test)$ https://localhost/rest/v1/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC,L,R]
```

How can I achieve getting the version path component and passing it in to the redirect URL?

Comment: It'd help if you provide your directory structure; location of htaccess file and explain the problem in a little depth

Comment: Update. I figured it out. I was testing in a htaccess file with intent of adding it to the config file. I didn't realise (although it's obvious now I know) that htaccess only has the scope of its own folder. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was testing in a htaccess file with intent of adding it to the config file. I didn't realise (although it's obvious now I know) that htaccess only has the scope of its own folder.